# How can i detect mouse pointer on my wpf user control?

Tags: wpf

I am using some animation on my user control code behind.

```
double height = canMain.ActualHeight - marqueeList.ActualHeight;
        marqueeList.Margin = new Thickness(0, height / 2, 0, 0);
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -marqueeList.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
        marqueeList.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

I want when i put my mouse on user control the animation should stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `MouseMove` event and check the `IsMouseOver` property

Comment: thanks for ur reply !! i updated my question now my code is also there can u please tell me how can i stop animation.iam using the above code for start animation and now i want to stop can you please help me on this according to above code

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `Storyboard.Stop()` method if you have started the animation setting the isControllable to true

```
Storyboard.Begin(this, true);
```

you also have the `Storyboard.Pause()` method if you plan to restart it again on some condition.

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

Try this too:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
      <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <!-- do your animation here (forever) -->
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.EnterActions>
      <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <!-- fake animation with duration set to 0 -->
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.ExitActions>          
    </Trigger>               
  </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies!!

I found my answer, I used mouse enter and mouse leave events for this.

On mouse enter :

```
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Right)"));
            _storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
            _storyBoard.Pause(marqueeList);
```

On mouse leave :

```
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Right)"));
        _storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        _storyBoard.Resume(marqueeList);
```